# Displaying Ad from Admob in UITableViewController

Tags: swift, swift3, admob, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to load native ads into my UITableViewController that uses an NSFetchedResultsController.  The ads display nothing (just white spice).  I have other types of ads working correctly (Interstitial and Banner) so I know Admob is configured correctly.  This is the relevant code below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "MyCell"
    let adCellIdentifier = "AdCell"
    if 1 == indexPath.row % 10{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: adCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AdTableViewCell

        cell.expressNativeAd = createNativeAdExpress()

        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    let Item = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    self.configureCell(cell, withItem: Item)
    return cell
}

func createNativeAdExpress() -> GADNativeExpressAdView {
    let adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-#/#"
    let nativeAdView = GADNativeExpressAdView()
    nativeAdView.adUnitID = adUnitId
    nativeAdView.rootViewController = self
    nativeAdView.delegate = self

    let videoOptions = GADVideoOptions()
    videoOptions.startMuted = true
    nativeAdView.setAdOptions([videoOptions])

    nativeAdView.videoController.delegate = self

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    nativeAdView.load(request)

    return nativeAdView
}
```

In addition to having blank ads, there is also the problem with my set up skipping items returned by NSFetchedResultsController.  If there are only four item returned, for instance, the second cell will be the blank Ad cell and then the third cell is third item returned by NSFetchedResultsController instead of continuing from the Second item.

In other words, because of the addition of the ad, i want 5 cells. 4 returned by NSFRC and 1 for the ad and for the ad to not be blank.

the adUnitID is the correct numbers in my code, not just #/# like I set up on here.

expressNativeAd is of type GADNativeExpressAdView